# How to add foreign key in rails migration with different table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

How can I assign different table name with adding foreign key. for e.g

I have a model like

```
class MyPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, class_name: PostComment
end

class PostComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, class_name: MyPost
end
```

Now i want to change my migration file like this:

```
class CreatePostComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :post_comments do |t|
     t.belongs_to :post, index: true
     t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :post, :class_name => MyPost
  end
end
```

But it is not working. Migration is getting cancelled. How do I change my migration file to work with my model structure.

Comment: `t.belongs_to :post, index: true` created the foreign key for you. Why again you are trying ? I am not getting what you are trying to do..

Comment: What's the error generated by your migration?

Answer (score 48):

You can pass in options for the foreign key as following:

```
class CreatePostComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :post_comments do |t|
      t.references :post, foreign_key: { to_table: :my_posts }, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This is also true for the index option if you like to add a unique constraint:

```
t.references :post, foreign_key: { to_table: :my_posts }, index: { unique: true}
```

By the way, references is an alias for `belongs_to`, or to be more exact, `belongs_to` is an alias for references.

See the details in the implementation [rails 5.0.rc2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.rc2/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L68) & [rails 4.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L312)

Comment: `index` is `true` by default. `index: true` is unnecessary.

Comment: [`index` is `true` by default from Rails 5](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference). [`index` is `false`by default on previous Rails versions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference).

Comment: I'd modify it to `t.references :post, foreign_key: { to_table: :my_posts }, null:false`, cause it won't add `null: false` by default

Answer (score 18):

It should look like this:

```
class CreatePostComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :post_comments do |t|
     t.belongs_to :post, index: true
     t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :post_comments, :my_posts, column: :post_id
  end
end
```

Take a look at the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key

You use the `column` option when the column is named differently.