# How to add database level foreign key in the migration file in rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have gone through some of similar question people asked but couldn't find the appropriate solution for it. I have also seen some people using this method - **add_foreign_key**

```
 class CreateTaskLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :task_lists do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :task_lists, :users
  end
end
```

but it is throwing undefined method error.

```
undefined method `add_foreign_key' for 
#<CreateTaskLists:0x007ffe9a5cd578>
/Users/sushilkumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/
activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/
migration.rb:624:in `block in method_missing'
```

[How to add foreign key in rails migration with different table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936481/how-to-add-foreign-key-in-rails-migration-with-different-table-name)
I don't know, How does this work for them?

Comment: What is the error? Please update it in your question.

Comment: @Pavan Updated with error

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try this way using `references`

```
class CreateTaskLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :task_lists do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :task_lists, :users
  end
end
```

Comment: I have updated the migration but it is still throwing error. Is there any gem required to enable add_foreign_key method?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key

Comment: Thanks Rajarshi, It was my mistake. I was using rails 4.0.0 version. Now it is working .. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class CreateTaskLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :task_lists do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :task_lists, :users
  end
end
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Did you meant to reference the table `User` and not `Users`? If so, you must use the singular (`:user`) when making a reference:

```
class CreateTaskLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :task_lists do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.references :user
     t.timestamps
   end
   add_foreign_key :task_lists, :users
 end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
class CreateTaskLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :task_lists do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :users, :task_lists
  end
end
```